# All minimum values in matrix optimization

Tags: dynamic, matrix, minimum

I have a matrix `nxn`, with positive integers. I have to calculate the cost for each element.

`Cost(i, j) = min( val(p, r) + dist(pos(i, j) ,pos(p, r)) ), p, r = 0:n-1`.

`dist(pos(i, j) ,pos(p, r)) = |i - p| + |j – r|` (Distance Manhattan)

I solved this in O(n^4) with something like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++)

  for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j ++) {
    int cost = 9999999;

    for(p = 0 ; p < n ; p ++) {

      for(r = 0 ; r < n ; r ++) {

        if( val[p][r] + abs(i-p) + abs(j-r)) < cost {

           cost = val[p][r] + abs(i-p) + abs(j-r);

        }

       }

     }

}
```

Now, I need an optimal solution in O(n^2). I know it's possible, and I heard that the solution would be programming dynamic, but I can not see how it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved in n^2. The idea is to iterate on lines(right-left and left-right) and columns(up-down and down-up).

void sort(int **v) {

//on lines

for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++) {

```
//left to right
for(int j = 1 ; j < n ; j ++) {
  if(v[i][j-1] + 1 < v[i][j])
    v[i][j] = 1 + v[i][j-1];
}
//right to left
for(int j = n-2 ; j >= 0 ; j --) {
  if(v[i][j+1] + 1 < v[i][j])
    v[i][j] = 1 + v[i][j+1];
}
```

}

//on columns

for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j ++) {

```
//up to down
for(int i = 1 ; i < n ; i ++) {
  if(v[i-1][j] + 1 < v[i][j])
    v[i][j] = 1 + v[i-1][j];
}
//down to up
for(int i = n-2 ; i >= 0 ; i --) {
  if(v[i+1][j] +1 <v[i][j])
    v[i][j] = 1 + v[i+1][j];
}
```

}
}